# iptables forward traffic from/to wireguard

Tags: iptables, vpn, nat, wireguard

Consider the following setup. I have a VPS that is connected to the internet, having a fixed IP. Further, in my home network, behind a NAT router, I do have my home network with several hosts. My home network uses the network `192.168.1.0/24`, and on Host1 I have configured a Wireguard VPN to my VPS. In this VPN, the VPS uses the IP `192.168.10.1` and the Host1 uses the IP `192.168.10.2`. From the VPS, I can ping the host in my home network and vice versa, this works fine.

Next I would like to access my home network from the VPS. For this, I have added a route on the VPS as follows

`ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.10.2 dev wg0`

with the idea that I could access different hosts on my home network from the VPS. However, I know that I need to enable the IP forwarding on Host1, which I did as follows:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens18 -j MASQUERADE`

and I have also configured `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`. With these two configurations, I can ping any host in my home network from the VPS. However, I have a web server in my home network, and when I try to access that one on my VPS, I get `no route to host` even though I can ping the web server. I ran `tcpdump` on Host1 in my home network and saw the error message `admin prohibited filter`, so it seems like HTTP traffic is not properly forwarded in contrast to ICMP. So how do I need to configure `iptables` to be able to access the web server in my home network on the VPS? I think I need to add NAT as well, but I am unsure how.

Comment: The `MASQUERADE` iptables rule you added _is_ NAT (it translates the source of packets forwarded out your `ens18` interface to use the interface's own IP address), so you don't need any more NAT. List the iptables rules you already have on Host1 with `iptables-save`, and nftables rules with `nft list ruleset` -- what you need depends on what you already have.

Answer (score 1):

You are certainly missing the additional [cryptokey routing](https://www.wireguard.com/#cryptokey-routing) entries in the server's WireGuard configuration.

The server's WireGuard layer has to know what is the peer matching for example the IP address `192.168.0.42`. For this it checks if there is a Peer with the right `AllowedIPs` entry. There's one peer defined and it very certainly has this entry:

```
AllowedIPs = 192.168.10.2
```

This didn't match `192.168.0.42` . The packet sent through the WireGuard interface to `192.168.0.42` is dropped.

So whenever additional routes are added to a *server* through its WireGuard interface (which typically doesn't use `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0/0/0` as a client would), chances are (one of) its `AllowedIPs` entry has to be changed accordingly too. In this case there should be:

```
 AllowedIPs = 192.168.10.2, 192.168.1.0/24
```

This will associate the destination to the right peer for egress, and validate received packets from this peer for ingress.

---

`iptables` didn't appear to be relevant for the problem.